# Compare local files to s3 bucket and determine what files (fullpath) are not in the bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, diff, local

I have a local file share that was copied to a snowball and imported to an s3 bucket (~70TB; many small files)
Since the import, users have added content to the local share. 
Im trying to get a list of all the files that are not present then transfer them to the bucket.

I've tried a sync and an s3cmd sync but it has to iterate through each item, my thoughts are if I export a list then run a copy only items that need to move it would save a lot of time.

Looking for some help on the simplest and fastest way to approach this

Comment: If you have a _huge_ number of files, it might be easier to obtain a listing via [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file of a bucket's contents.

Comment: Any easy to compare both lists? chances are they will be unsorted and wont have exactly the same path. 

is there a way to map the s3 bucket and use something like dir /s /b or find "$PWD" to generate the list?

Comment: You would need to write some code to compare the CSV file from Amazon S3 Inventory with the contents of the local share. But, at least it avoids having to make calls to AWS to retrieve S3 contents.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can go this way if you assume your files weren't changed, i.e. if file path is uniquely identifies the content. Additionally you could check if the size remained the same.

To get list of objects in an s3 bucket use [list-objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html):

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket text-content --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, Size: Size}')
```